# Using data that is not in common from csv files/Did it

Tags: r

Is there a way to only use data from one CSV file that is not the same as this other CSV file? I recently split some data to conduct EFA and CFA analysis. I need to not use the information that will use to conduct the EFA analysis because then it serves no point to randomly split the data.

So how do I only use the data that I did not use in the CFA? If anyone can help please, it would be much appreciated.

Edit:

what I did was the following

```
Usage <-anti_join(file one, file two, by ='the column in which I could separate by')
```

then I just exported the file into a CSV, thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large, as well as the complete code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We can probably help you, but we would need more information, as @neilfws has indicated. You might for example, clarify what you mean by "data"? Perhaps you mean there are two csvs, one which is a subset of rows from the other, and you would like to exclude that subset of rows?  Please help us understand more.

Comment: Sure! I have one cleaned CSV file that has over 5,000 rows, from that I split some of that data for EFA, so that file is around 740 rows. I want to exclude that subset of rows yes that is correct, sorry it's my first time using R so I am a little confused and did not know where else to look.

Comment: dplyr's `anti_join` is probably helpful here.

Comment: How would I use that? Sorry, again I know the basics.